# Insert plus-minus Unicode character into SQL Server DB (TSQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a CSV file in UTF8 encoding and I would like to import data into SQL Server DB table.
In some cells I have stored values like:

```
±40%;
16.5±10%;
```

All columns load perfectly but only columns with **±** character show in DB this:

[image]

All columns where I would like to store this character I use ***nvarchar(50)*** with collation ***Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_WS_SC_UTF8***

Is there any wait how this character store into DB ?
Thank you

---

EDIT
I use for load CSV file this:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[x]
    FROM 'c:\Users\x\Downloads\x.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'c:\Users\x\Downloads\xx.csv',
    TABLOCK
    );
```

I also try to change SSMS Options:

```
‘Tools‘ -> ‘Options‘ -> ‘Environment‘ -> ‘Fonts and Colors‘ -> Select ‘Grid Results’
```

Set Font to Arial but without positive results

I have over 20 million records in many files, which I want to import

Comment: Do you have to do this often? Otherwise a `REPLACE` after the load may be enough.

Comment: So SSMS is not _displaying_ the value correctly. Doesn't mean it isn't stored correctly. Have a play with the `Char()` function to interrogate what value is actually stored.

Comment: Ok, but is there any chance to set SSMS 2020 on SQL Server 2019 to show it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `CODEPAGE=65001` (UTF-8) to the `WITH` clause of the `BULK INSERT` statement?

Comment: @marc_s Thank you, Its works, please change your comment like Answer and I mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a `CODEPAGE=65001` (UTF-8) to the `WITH` clause of the `BULK INSERT` statement?

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[x]
FROM 'c:\Users\x\Downloads\x.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'c:\Users\x\Downloads\xx.csv',
    CODEPAGE = 65001,
    TABLOCK
);
```